# Saving any file in eclipse giving me following error:

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt, lint

An internal error occurred during: "Running Android Lint".
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/UnionTypeReference
[image: Lint Error]

Any solution?? i am not able to work because of it.

Comment: What version of Eclipse and Android SDK Tools do you have?

Comment: Eclipse Version: 1.9.0.v201106031100-7B7C7CCcNBGNCYJ_DVWY
Build id: 1.7.2.v20110603-0500                                                              Android SDK and ADT v22.6.2

Comment: That doesn't sound like an Eclipse version number to me, more like an SQL developer plugin version no. What does your Eclipse say on start up splash screen? I suspect it's 'Helios'. In which case it will never support Java 7 language features. You need at least 'Indigo'. If you upgrade go straight to 'Kepler', or if feeling brave go for the pre-release 'Luna'

Comment: @shriduttkothari I am facing the same problem, did you solve it? if yes please share it's very annoying...

Comment: @E_X added answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ) is too old in Eclipse 3.6. see [Issue 66226](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66226) However it's allegedly been fixed in Tools 22.6 according to that bug report.

Comment: so what i need to do??

Comment: Upgrade both the Android SDK and ADT to v22.6.2.

Comment: @CKDPublishing i already have Latest Updated Android SDK and ADT v22.6.2 and on checking update it says no update

Comment: You should also be running JDK v6 (1.6.45) instead of v7. JDK v7 is not yet supported by Android.

Comment: Java 7 is supported but you must set compliance level to 1.6. You must also have at least Eclipse Indigo. Helios won't support Java 7 language features.